# Using input() without ">?" in pycharm

Tags: python, input, pycharm

I am new to pycharm and python. I am trying to use `input()`. I have a basic but annoying problem. Every time the input prompt is followed with a `>?`.

For example,

```
input('what is your name?')
what is your name?>? robin
Out[8]: 'robin'
```

Is it possible to do it without `>?`, like this?

```
input('what is your name?')
what is your name? robin
Out[8]: 'robin'
```

Comment: Hum. Didn't know that could happen. Have you tried `r"string"`. I don't see this on my end btw.

Comment: Cannot reproduce with Pycharm 2019.3 - I created a file: `main.py` and added `inp = input('what is your name?')`.

Comment: @Mike-SMT sorry, what is r"string"?

Comment: r stands for raw string. It might work.

Comment: @MannanBhardwaj this same..donno why

Comment: It does the same for me, my understanding is that it hints the user that an input is required in the console for the call to keep on running. Let's put some context, you run a script and don't know that an input is required at some point, thanks to the `>?` symbol, as the user, you can know that an input is expected from you.